# Hibernate Batch Operation performance

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, batch-processing

I have around 5000 records to update. I am trying to measure performance of the operation. It starts with around 100 ms but after every thousand updates operation time increases around 80 ms. Why is it slowing down? JVM?

```
StatelessSession session = dao.getStatelessSession();
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
try {
    List<Entity> list = dao.findAll();
    int counter = 0;
    for (Entity each : list) {
        final Date startTime = Clock.getTime();
        webService.execute(each);
        session.update(each);
        counter += 1;
        final Date endTime = Clock.getTime();
        LOGGER.info("***** " + getMilliSecondsDifference(startTime, endTime) + " for count: " + counter + "*****");
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    LOGGER.info("***** Exception occured : ", e);
} finally {
    transaction.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Comment: Would be also a webService call. What makes you think of hibernate is getting slower ? I suggest you to close werbservice execute part and measure it again.

Comment: After closing webservice call i tried with 15000 entities and all of them are around 4 ms. This seems like the answer but i can't accept comment as answer. Can you post this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hüseyin,

It doesnt have to be hibernate problem at all if we look at your code.
I suggest you to comment out your line related with webservice call.

Then please try again batch hql running.

Maybe networking could be getting slower.

Answer (score 0):

You have one transaction and dealing with a large number of objects. here you will probabely have a memory leak and performance issue too.
The objects references will stay in memory untill a session flush is executed (commit). so you will have a big number of object in memory in addition of the big number of informations about the object changes that will be also kept in the hibernate session and that can alter the performance too (i'am not an hibernate expert but you should consider this point)
I think that you may think about using a lot of transactions

See theses interesting links:

[Transaction Management for bulk operations](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/development-resources/confluence-architecture/hibernate-sessions-and-transaction-management-guidelines/hibernate-session-and-transaction-management-for-bulk-operations)

[Hibernate session and Transaction Management Guidelines](https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/development-resources/confluence-architecture/hibernate-sessions-and-transaction-management-guidelines)

Good luck

Comment: I am using StatelessSession which doesn't keep every dirty object. Even for normal session multiple transactions are unnecessary. You just need to flush and clear. I measured with multiple transactions as you said and it is same.

Comment: I see, This  make it more complicated, you can try to see if it's either caused by the webservice call or the database. try ignore one of them and see the results (for example ignore the update and keep the webservice call)